# Django request should run in background?

Tags: django

When user submit request, the request should run in background so that user should not wait for the request complete and update to user via email/slack channel?

i have a request to ssh and performs the task, so some commands/tasks will take longer time to completed, that's why i'm looking this option

What is the better way to achieve?

Comment: You should work with an queueing mechanism like RabbitMQ, such that the request adds a message to the queue and then invoke a method when you receive the message. For example with *Django celery*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For django you can use Celery with rabbitmq or reddis for achieving the asynchronous programming in that way user will not have to wait for them to be complete
using celery you have to turn that email sending function in a task and call that function in view with email_function.delay(*args)
you can refer this link for celery documentation
https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html

Comment: Worth commenting here – from very painful experience – that you need to study *very closely* how Celery, rabbitmq, and/or reddis *actually work.* There are subtleties here which can really bite the uninformed.  (Like I was. Ouch.)  Once you clearly understand what these packages are doing "behind the scenes," you should have no problems, but you *do* need to know that.

Comment: yeah agree with your point but all I was willing to give him an overview of the solution because all that is not possible to include in a single answer.
 for celery setup, you can refer to celery documentation:  https://docs.celeryproject.org/en/stable/django/first-steps-with-django.html